# System of equations wrong solution $(x, y, z) = (3, 3, 2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

> Find the real solutions for the following system of 2 equations: 
> $z^2 - 4z = -9 - 2xy$ 
> $x(x - 6 - y) + y(y - 6 - x) = -13$ (A book of problems for 8th graders)

The book says that $(x, y, z) = (3, 3, 2)$ is the only solution for the problem. However the numbers seem not to be suitable for the equations. Which is the true solution of the system if there is one? Or there are none in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You are correct that $(3,3,2)$ does not match the problem as written.  This should be quick and easy to verify, since plugging those values into the second equation, this becomes $3(-6)+3(-6)=-13$ which is incorrect

Comment: As for solutions... let $x$ be a free variable.  Then $y$ can be written in terms of $x$ based on the second equation.  Now, $z$ can be written exclusively in terms of $x$ using that based on the first equation.  [The results aren't pretty](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E2-4z%3D-9-2xy%2C+x%28x-6-y%29%2By%28y-6-x%29%3D-13).  I strongly suspect there must be typos in the problem.